# How to sort a list into even then odd numbers using recursion when the function can only call itself and use basic list manipulations

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

The function takes in a list of integers and returns a list of the same elements sorted into the order of even integers then odd ones. Im struggling with implementing a recursive function to complete it even though I am able to solve this using a for loop.

```
def sort(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l1.append(i)
        else:
            l2.append(i)
    x = l1 + l2
    return x
```

```
def eto(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:

    if len(lst) == 1
        return lst
    else:
        y = lst[0]
        x = lst[1:]
        return(eto(x))
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Note that using `lst[1:]` repeatedly like that is extremely inefficient in python. Also, using recursion like that is extremely inefficient in python. Although python supports recursion, it's really not meant to be used as the main control flow tool. Splitting a list into a head and a tail like that works well in functional programming languages such as Ocaml and Haskell, but will often be very inefficient in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose we are allowed to reorder the odd numbers, as long as they are in the second part of the list. I completed your proposition:

```
def eto(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:

    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst

    head = lst[0]
    tail = lst[1:]
    if head % 2 == 0:
        return [head] + eto(tail)
    return eto(tail) + [head]
```